# Spring + Hibernate Transaction Management using Remote JNDI Datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, jta, spring-transactions

I have a Spring application, that uses hibernate, Spring transaction management and a JNDI datasource located on Weblogic server.

*Application works fine when deployed on weblogic*, however it throws following error when running on local as a standalone java application (without container) -

> org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name
>   [javax.transaction.TransactionManager] 
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property

Here is the transaction manager, datasource and hibernate configuration I am using in my setup:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"></bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/mydatasource"/>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment" ref="weblogicJndiEnv"></property>
</bean>

<util:properties id="weblogicJndiEnv">
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">weblogic</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">weblogic</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://#{ systemProperties['listenurl'] }</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="abc.xyz" />
</bean>
```

Is there anything I am missing in the above configuration?

Comment: do you have the same datasource configured on the local machine?

Comment: No, the datasource is on remote weblogic server

Comment: Note: I am running it on local as a standalone java application (outside container)